# How can i make this code more general

Tags: c#

I want to use this method with different Classes

so is there a way to cast this variable *Collection* to a different methods

because i have four classes like RSummary

```
//ResultQuery : i want to cast this variable more than one Type  eg : 
var collection = await ResultQuery(entity, _classId).Cast<RSummary>().ToListAsync();
foreach (var result in collection)
{
    decimal Percentile = 0;
    int Rank = 0;
    // Rank
    if (result.Percentage == Percentile)
        result.Rank = Rank; 
    else
    {
        result.Rank = Rank + 1; Percentile = result.Percentage; Rank++;
    }
    var Values = await GetGrades(result.Percentage); //returns student GPA, Grade, etc.
    result.Grade = Values.Grade; 
    result.Description= Values.Description;
    result.GPA = Values.GPA;
    Values = null;
    entity.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Rsummary class

```
public class RSummary
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ExamsId { get; set; }
public string StudentsId { get; set; }
public decimal HM { get; set; }
public decimal Marks { get; set; }
public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
public string Grade { get; set; }
public int Rank { get; set; }
public string Result { get; set; }
public decimal GPA { get; set; }

public virtual Exam Exams { get; set; }
public virtual Student Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a common interface that `RSummary` shares with the other classes? For example, do the other types have a `Percentage`, `Rank`, etc properties?

Comment: Yes actually they do. @EvanTrimboli

Comment: Then ppost at least one other class and any common interface or base class.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are properties in common, you could do something like this with an interface and generics

```
public interface IMyAwesomeInterface
{
   decimal Percentage { get; set; }
   int Grade { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
   decimal GPA { get; set; }
   int  Rank { get; set; }
}

public void SomeMethod<T>(Entity entity, int classId)
   where T : IMyAwesomeInterface
{
   var collection = await ResultQuery(entity, classId).Cast<T>().ToListAsync();
   foreach (var result in collection)
   {
      decimal Percentile = 0;
      int Rank = 0;
      if (result.Percentage == Percentile)
         result.Rank = Rank;
      else
      {
         result.Rank = Rank + 1;
         Percentile = result.Percentage;
         Rank++;
      }
      var Values = await GetGrades(result.Percentage); //returns student GPA, Grade, etc.
      result.Grade = Values.Grade;
      result.Description = Values.Description;
      result.GPA = Values.GPA;
      Values = null;
      entity.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
   }
}
```

**Disclaimer** : just an example based on the code supplied, i take no responsibility for your business logic and other problems, or the harm this could do to children